# How to get the changed scope variables after compiling the directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

After I change a value of variable in controller and compile the directive, I am still getting the old value of variable itself instead of new. Ideally I think for below code, I should get the result as "New Value" but I am getting as "Old value". Please help!

My Controller:

```
app.controller("MainCont",['$compile', function($scope,$http,$compile){
        $scope.var1 = false;
        $changeName = function(){
            $scope.var1 = true;
            angular.element(someElement).append($compile("<new-dir></new-dir>")($scope));
        }
    }]);
```

My Directive

```
app.directive("newDir",function(){
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        controller: 'MainCont',
        link: function(scope,element){
            if(!scope.var1){
                console.log("Old Value");
            }else{
                console.log("New Value");
            }

        }
    }
    return directive;
})
```

Comment: $compile is missing as injection on your controller code.

Comment: Why do you need to compile while changing scope value. There is some other way to track that. Please explain your original requirement.

Comment: In the directive linking function, you name the first argument `scope`; but in the subsequent `if` statement, you use `$scope`.

Comment: Hey George, Thanks. Edited the question.

Comment: @Partha Sarathi Ghosh, I dont want the element <new-dir> on my initial page load. Wanted to create it over a function call.

Comment: Use ng-if to show on a function call.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a directive `<new-dir></new-dir>`

You can make that visible over a function call using a variable like `var1`

```
    $changeName = function(){
        $scope.var1 = true;
    }
```

then use this view template as

`<new-dir ng-if="var1"></new-dir>`